# Can this state management be done on the react？

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, jsx, antd

[the code is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WGMD.png)

I want to know that is right? thanks!

Comment: Can you please post the code in the question, and not an image of it?

Comment: Welcome to SO. When you are posting a question here try to give more and more details about your problem. This is how you get the best answers and avoid being downvoted :) Images are not useful as you can guess. When you have some free time, visit [the related help center page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) about asking good questions.

Comment: I suggest reading [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, Please post your code in the question and describe clearly

With getLabels function, you should bind(this) in constructor or use arrow function then you can this.setState in getLabels function. 
ex:

```
constructor(props){
  super(props)
 this.getLabels = this.getLabels.bind(this)
}
```

Or: 
    getLabels = () => {}

Comment: May I add JSX to state on the react

Comment: Add JSX? It mean component? You can import component and set into state of component in react

Answer (score 0):

You can manage state with `react` if your application is small, [refer here](https://medium.com/react-ecosystem/how-to-handle-state-in-react-6f2d3cd73a0c) to know how to maintain `state` in `react`.

when your applications grows big its difficult to track the `state`, you may have to go for `redux`,  [refer here](https://redux.js.org/basics) to know more about `redux`.

Comment: May I add JSX to state on the react

Answer (score 0):

First thing first. "getLabels" functions name is wrong. "setLabels" would be a better name since what you do is assigning the labels to state after retrieving them. So if the rest of the code written correctly it'll trigger a re-render in the component and the UI will be updated with the new state.

if this gets called from a UI button or something, then you'll have to bind to this.

```
<input type="button" onClick={this.getLabels.bind(this)}/>
```

Else if it get's called from another function in the same component you can just call it.

```
function abc(){
  this.getLabels()
}
```

Other than that this is ok for a basic app. But it's better you use some state management pattern like Redux to manage the code and the state.

Comment: May I add JSX to state on the react

Comment: I'm not very clear about your question.
Basically JSX is the syntax we use in ReactJS.
Actually State contains the data of the app. In side a component what you do is use that state to build the UI with JSX syntax.